# Firebase Google Authentication Says: Access blocked: This app’s request is invalid

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have linked my domain in the firebase authentication, and I have allowed access for auth too.

If you would like to try it, here is the link
https://colesprojects.ml/signin/

```
signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
  .then((result) => {
    // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
    const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
    const token = credential.accessToken;
    // The signed-in user info.
    const user = result.user;


    alert(user.displayName);
    // ...
  }).catch((error) => {
    // Handle Errors here.
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    // The email of the user's account used.
    const email = error.email;
    // The AuthCredential type that was used.
    const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
    // ...

    alert(errorMessage);
  });
 });
```

Here is my code if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the error, it seems to me you didn't add your domain to your **Authorized redirect URIs**.
Go to the [GCP console Credentials configuration](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials), in the **OAuth 2.0 Client IDs** section select your app and add your redirect url to the **Authorized redirect URIs** section at the bottom (here your redirect URI would be *https://colesprojects.ml/__/auth/handler* as stated in the error).
[image: Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch]